# Manually consuming messages in onMessage method of MDB

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean

I am trying to consume messages in onMessage method, because I want several messages in one transaction to improve performance.

But

```
Message message = consumer.receive();
```

returns null. It doesn't even block. Buy why? It must be blocked until it gets message, isn't it?

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    QueueConnection queueConnection = null;     
    queueConnection = qcf.createQueueConnection();
    queueConnection.start();
    queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue queue = queueSession.createQueue(sessionConnParams.toString());
    consumer = queueSession.createConsumer(queue);

    // it works in cycle
    System.out.println("before receive");
    Message message = consumer.receive();
    System.out.println("after receive");
    if (message == null) {
       System.out.println("no messages");
       return;
    }

   // process message

   } catch (Exception e) {
     // process exception
   } finally {
     // close objects
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I add this tag by accident.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to create consumer and receive messages inside an onMessage() of a MDB because the purpose of calling onMessage() method is to deliver a message? So why call receive again?

Comment: Yes, it is. I need to get several messages in one transaction to improve performance. I'm not aware about other options.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion creating another receiver in onMessage() is not a good idea. EJB specifications does not recommend starting threads in OnMessage methods.

Receiving multiple messages in one transaction will not improve performance. Performance depends on multiple factors

1) Time taken by `onMessage` method to process a message.

2) How fast the messaging provider is delivering messages

3) Network

4) Hardware

To improve performance you can consider running multiple MDBs in parallel. Also look at the performance tuning of the messaging provider you are using.

Here is one useful link from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0508_parkinson/0508_parkinson.html)

Comment: No, I can't use multiple MDBs, because I need to preserve messages order. And I'm not going to start a new thread.

Comment: "Receiving multiple messages in one transaction will not improve performance" - It significantly improves performance, because committing creates huge overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're unlikely to get JMS to do what you want if you're running into a global transaction. If you use

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

this will force the application server to run in an unspecified transaction context. What this means is completely dependent on which application server you are using. If you are using Websphere Application Server, it means that the bean runs outside of a transaction and so operations like sending and receiving messages do what you'd expect them to. Other application servers may handle this differently - read the documentation. Regardless, doing that is probably a bad idea. You're working against the application server.

The JMS spec defines a mechanism for batching up the delivery of messages. IBM Websphere MQ calls this read-ahead http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc%2Fjm41130_.htm and it allows for multiple messages to be read off the queue at once and delivered to the application one after the other. Other JMS implementations probably support something similar.

Ultimately though, if your application requires that messages always be processed in order, you're going to have to deal with the overhead of committing each message before processing the next. The commit overhead almost certainly is much greater than the overhead of delivering a message to an MDB. Trying to hack in something to read extra messages inside an MDB won't get you around that. If that is an issue for you, you should probably look to make changes to the application to be able to process messages out-of-order.